# How do I access my saved links in Facebook via the 2.5 API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have had a crack at this on the Graph API Explorer, but it returns nothing, not even an error. I used the API endpoint `save.saves` as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/).

[image]

Comment: Don't know why I was down-voted. It is an absolutely valid question? Weird community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You referenced a link to the Open Graph stories section in the docs, that´s something completely different. Afaik there is no way to get access to the saved links with the Graph API, at least not at the moment. If they ever make it available, you will find the endpoint here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user

Comment: Aha, I see. So the only way to extract them is scraping them I believe.

Comment: There has to be a way to get those links outta facebook programmatically mate.

Comment: no legal one, so: no. there´s not always away, some things are just not possible.